# How to use some ruby with objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ruby, cocoa

I don't want to go the full rubyobjc, how would I be able to use a few ruby-terms in my cocoa/objective-c code?

The reason I want to switch is because I really like ruby's syntax.  It's awesome!
If it's not possible, then I'm wondering if rubyobjc is good...

Unfortunately I've heard that when using rubyobjc there isn't a nib/interface builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/), I was just watching a [screencast](http://peepcode.com/products/meet-macruby) on it the other day and he was able to use Interface Builder and call objective-c methods and ruby methods together to build a simple osx desktop app.

And now that Apple has lifted restrictions on iOS software, it might be possible to use it for iPhone/iPad development.

Comment: MacRuby is not usable for iOS development, mainly due to the fact that it requires garbage collection in the system frameworks.

Comment: Apparently Apple is working on it, though: https://twitter.com/applespotlight/status/24302410536

Comment: Thanks, I just looked at some example code and it's really cool!  Although I'm having many difficulties installing though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix Ruby terms or syntax into Objective-C source files. You may be able to make some classes in Ruby (with MacRuby) and other classes in Objective-C, though.

Comment: How?  Would you recommend a weird `rb_main.rb` + `class.m/h` hybrid, or vice-versa?